# MYSQL - problema con ORDER BY de una columna de valores iguales

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta MYSQL :

```
SELECT *, 
       (
          SELECT SUM(points) 
          FROM point 
          WHERE employeeId=employee.id
        ) as totalPoints 
FROM employee 
ORDER BY totalPoints DESC
```

Como pueden ver es una lista ordenada simple por la cantidad de puntos de cada trabajador, el objetivo es formar un ranking simple por puntaje, el problema es que hay muchos trabajadores con el mismo puntaje (ejemplo 10) entonces al hacer la consulta la posición empieza a variar. Por ejemplo obtengo esta lista :

```
nombre    | apellido | puntaje
--------------------------------
Juan      | Perez    | 120
Pepe      | Suarez   | 100
Ricardo   | Cruzado  | 80
Carlos    | Medina   | 80
Jesus     | Segura   | 80
Alberto   | Veocinco | 50
Guillermo | Cabrejos | 20
Antonio   | Pereyda  | 10
```

Ahora centrarse en los 3 trabajadores que tienen puntaje 80, cada vez que llamo a la consulta el señor ricardo cruzado por ejemplo que esta antes que el señor carlos medina puede aparecer debajo del mismo o al final y las posiciones de los mismos varian cada vez que llamo a la consulta, por ejemplo obtengo lo siguiente :

```
nombre    | apellido  | puntaje
--------------------------------
Juan      | Perez     | 120
Pepe      | Suarez    | 100
Jesus     | Segura    | 80
Carlos    | Medina    | 80
Ricardo   | Cruzado   | 80
Alberto   | Veocinco  | 50
Guillermo | Cabrejos  | 20
Antonio   | Pereyda   | 10
```

y si llamo otra vez obtengo :

```
nombre    | apellido  | puntaje
--------------------------------
Juan      | Perez     | 120
Pepe      | Suarez    | 100
Jesus     | Segura    | 80
Ricardo   | Cruzado   | 80
Carlos    | Medina    | 80
Alberto   | Veocinco  | 50
Guillermo | Cabrejos  | 20
Antonio   | Pereyda   | 10
```

Y así con todos los trabajadores que tienen un mismo puntaje.

Me gustaría saber si hay una mejor manera de aplicar la consulta.
Gracias de antemano !

Comment: No se entiende bien cuál es el problema, ni lo que quieres decir con esto: *entonces al hacer la consulta la posición empieza a variar* . Puedes [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/173502/edit) explicando mejor la situación, y si es posible, poniendo algún ejemplo del resultado que obtienes y del resultado que esperas obtener.

Comment: José, si lo que buscas es que dentro del grupo de los empleados que tienen el mismo puntaje se mantenga siempre un orden determinado, debes agregar una segunda columna en el `ORDER` por ejemplo el apellido.

Comment: Para agregar a lo que dice Patricio, ninguna base de datos puede asegurar que la misma consulta devuelva los mismos valores en el mismo orden siempre, A MENOS, que se indique con un order by, y en ese caso solo se asegura que esos valores estan ordenados. Si queres mas orden, tenes que agregar mas columnas

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta, básicamente todos los usuarios que tienen un mismo puntaje al llamar nuevamente a la consulta pueden variar de posicion así como he puesto en el ejemplo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Propondré una solución basada en `JOIN`.

Aquí puedes ver los datos de prueba que se han usado: <kbd>**[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/GAQ21893)**</kbd>.

Por ejemplo, esta consulta establece dos tipos de orden:

- `DESC`endente por el total de puntos
- `ASC`endente combinando `apellido,nombre`

  ```
  SELECT 
      e.apellido, 
      e.nombre, 
      SUM(p.points) puntos 
  FROM employee_20180615 e 
  INNER JOIN point_20180615 p
  ON e.employee_id=p.employee_id
  GROUP BY e.employee_id
  ORDER BY puntos DESC, e.apellido,e.nombre ASC;
  ```

El resultado sería parecido a :

```
apellido    nombre      puntos
Pérez       Juan        120
Cruzado     Ricardo     80
Medina      Carla       80
Medina      Carlos      80
Segura      Jesús       80
```

Esta otra consulta establece el orden así:

- `DESC`endente por el total de puntos
- `ASC`endente combinando `nombre,apellido`

  ```
  SELECT 
      e.nombre, 
      e.apellido, 
      SUM(p.points) puntos 
  FROM employee_20180615 e 
  INNER JOIN point_20180615 p
  ON e.employee_id=p.employee_id
  GROUP BY e.employee_id
  ORDER BY puntos DESC, e.nombre,e.apellido ASC;
  ```

El resultado sería más o menos:

```
nombre      apellido    puntos
Juan        Pérez       120
Carla       Medina      80
Carlos      Medina      80
Jesús       Segura      80
Ricardo     Cruzado     80
```

Como podrás apreciar, se pueden **combinar** no solamente columnas para participar de un mismo orden, sino que también se pueden combinar **secuencias** de orden, por ejemplo, le puedes pedir que ordene de forma descendente por la(s) columna(s) `X,Y` y de forma ascendente por la(s) columnas `A,B`.

Sabiendo eso, puedes ordenar como mejor te convenga.

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Claro, la idea era básicamente hacer el ranking basado en el puntaje, mi limitante era que el ordenamiento por otros campos afecte los resultados de la consulta pero con tu ejemplo me queda más que claro, muchas gracias!

Porcierto creo que aplicado a mi consulta inicial, con tu ejemplo sería esta :


    SELECT *, 
           (
              SELECT SUM(points) 
              FROM point 
              WHERE employeeId=employee.id
            ) as totalPoints 
    FROM employee 
    ORDER BY totalPoints DESC, id ASC

Comment: @JoseLoguercio me alegra de que te haya servido. En el ejemplo que pones el segundo ordenamiento lo haría por el `id`. No obstante, siempre es mejor usar `JOIN`,  pues de ese modo el manejador usará los índices y las consultas serán más eficaces, sobre todo en tablas con gran cantidad de datos.